# Log4j writes into catalina.out

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j, catalina

I want to redirect application specific logger into a separate file from **tomcat/logs/catalina.out**.

Here is the content of **log4j.xml** file content which is residing at **tomcat/lib** folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

 <appender name="RollingFiles" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">

        <param name="file" value="${catalina.home}/logs/application.log"/>        
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%p-%d-{%C}-%t-%x-%m%n"/>
        </layout>
 </appender>

 <logger name="com.company">
        <level value="debug"/>
 </logger>

 <root>
        <priority value ="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFiles" />
 </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Here is the content of **logging.properties** presented inside **tomcat/conf** folder

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler


1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = manager.

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = host-manager.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter


org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].handlers = 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

But still I am getting all logger output in catalina.out and application.log, but I don't want application specific log (i.e logger name="com.company") in catalina.out. Kindly help me on this.

Tomcat version : 7.0.35
Java : 1.7.0_45
Log 4j : log4j-1.2.16.jar

Comment: how about java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = OFF

Comment: I tried this, but didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is, I referred a jar in my project which has **org.pentaho.di.core.logging.LogWriter**  class. It by default adding console logger into the root logger.

The fix is, removed it from LogWriter

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your log4j.xml file under your app root directory :
webbapps/[your app]/WEB-INF/classes

This way you are not depend on a specific tomcat installation for your logging and you can deploy your app on any tomcat instance without changing the default tomcat configuration.

Comment: How to specify which log goes into which file?

Comment: <logger name="com.company">
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFiles"/>
  </logger>

Comment: But the the also goes into catalina.out also, what to do?

Comment: have you tried to add additivity="false" ?  <logger name="com.company" additivity="false"> <appender-ref ref="RollingFiles"/> </logger>